# how we can send mails out of salesforce using apex with different from addresses?

Tags: apex, email

how we can send mails out of salesforce using apex with different from addresses? i am not getting any idea.please provide a hint.how i used this code.

```
global class CreateTaskEmailExample implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                   Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){

// Create an InboundEmailResult object for returning the result of the 
// Apex Email Service
Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

String myPlainText= '';

// Add the email plain text into the local variable 
myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;

// New Task object to be created
Task[] newTask = new Task[0];

// Try to look up any contacts based on the email from address
// If there is more than one contact with the same email address,
// an exception will be thrown and the catch statement will be called.
try {
  Contact vCon = [SELECT Id, Name, Email
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress
    LIMIT 1];

  // Add a new Task to the contact record we just found above.
  newTask.add(new Task(Description =  myPlainText,
       Priority = 'Normal',
       Status = 'Inbound Email',
       Subject = email.subject,
       IsReminderSet = true,
       ReminderDateTime = System.now()+1,
       WhoId =  vCon.Id));

   // Insert the new Task 
   insert newTask;    

 System.debug('New Task Object: ' + newTask );   
}
// If an exception occurs when the query accesses 
// the contact record, a QueryException is called.
// The exception is written to the Apex debug log.
catch (QueryException e) {
   System.debug('Query Issue: ' + e);
}

// Set the result to true. No need to send an email back to the user 
// with an error message
result.success = true;

 // Return the result for the Apex Email Service
 return result;
 }
}
```

Comment: Gopinath.. this is not clear what you are looking for? if you just want to send email then below Anu's code will work..

Comment: Hey sorry, generally we will use To address tosend email in vf page but here i need FROM adress Box also if i enter lgn@sfdc.com in FROM adress and l@gmail.com in TO adress

Comment: You can use `fromAddress` property of `Messaging.inboundEmail` check docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm#apex_Messaging_InboundEmail_fromAddress

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
public static void sendEmail(String emailBody){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'alin@test.com','anuraj@test.com'};       
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setSubject('Loyalie Info');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Email Body '+ emailBody);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand the term what is "emails out of salesforce using apex"

Comment: Hi Anu,could you please explain what is the word "email sending out of salesforce using apex"

Comment: Not based on login user. User can manaully provide FROM address....It can be any email address out side of salesforce also.like...u r sening email from sfdc but  when user receive email, it looks like, I have sent and not urname

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it right but assuming that you can get email from object.Then just based on some condition , you set the email from FromAddress , you also can use fromName.

Example

```
List<Contact> listContact = [select Email,Name from Contact where whatevercondition];

// Create a new email, envelope object and Attachment
   Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
   Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
   Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment inAtt = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();

   email.subject = 'test';

for(Contact c: listContact){
  env.fromName =c.Name;
 env.fromAddress =c.Email;

}
```